# How uninstall pycharm and rubymine?

Tags: python, ruby, ubuntu, rubymine, pycharm

I installed pycharm and rubymine on linux mint, my trial has ended. how to remove them? can i just do

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge pycharm
```

or is there an `uninstall.sh` somewhere?

Comment: How did you intall them?

Comment: @RomanA.Taycher for pycharm i ran `pycharm.sh` and for rubymine i ran `rubymine.sh` these files are in the `bin` sub-directory of pycharm and rubymine

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The standard `tar.gz` packages seem to be self contained directories with the application in the manner of eclipse, so to uninstall just delete the directories.

Comment: One may also want to delete config/cache/plugin directories, see http://devnet.jetbrains.net/docs/DOC-181.

Comment: As a convenience, the current version : https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23358108

Comment: In arch after pacman uninstall I run ` find /  -iname "*Pycharm*"` which found those : `/home/utumno/.PyCharm30`
`/home/utumno/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop`
`/home/utumno/.gnome/apps/jetbrains-pycharm.desktop` - I guess removing those would cleanly uninstall