# Uninstall PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I'm trying to uninstall PyCharm Community 3.0.

```
$ sudo apt-get remove --purge pycharm
```

I'm using that command but unfortunately it doesn't work.
the prompt says

> "E: Unable to locate package pycharm"

What's the best for it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How uninstall pycharm and rubymine?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9940451/how-uninstall-pycharm-and-rubymine)

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to uninstall a package using `apt-get` unless that package is installed using `apt-get`. To install a package using `apt-get`, it should be present in the repositories.

Anyway, installing PyCharm is as simple as downloading the package (a tar.gz or zip file), extracting it and running it. The first run should automatically setup the environment.

So, uninstalling / removing PyCharm should be possible by removing the directory. Perhaps you may need to delete some temporaray files. Check for some dot files using `ls -la` in terminal and ensure that they are PyCharm related files before removing them.

Answer (score 1):

Just delete the pycharm directory.
No need terminal operation for removing.
It is same as deleting a file.